# Assets not found when deploying Sails app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sails.js

I'm pretty new in Sails.

I've created a new web-app from the Sails template and tried to upload it to Heroku. Everything was fine except for the assets, none of the assets are found (js, css, images, etc).

I've found out that Sails uses Grunt for copying the files to a .tmp folder. I've checked and I have Grunt added to my `package.json` file. I've also added a Procfile wit the `web: node app.js` command and the `NODE_ENV` variable it's pointing to `production` in Heroku.

I didn't changed any of the Grunt tasks, the `Gruntfile.js` file and the `/tasks` directory are by default.

Any ideas of what else I could check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue through a different mean.  On top of including some of the `grunt` deps in the OP's answer, I added `postinstall` in the scripts section of `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run custom-tests && echo 'Done.'",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look so good.' && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && echo '✔  So do your .ejs files.' && lesshint assets/styles/ --max-warnings=0 && echo '✔  Your .less files look good, too.'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo",
    "postinstall": "grunt build", // added this
...
```

The effect of this on heroku is the required running of the grunt task `build`, which compile and copy the assets to the appropriately referenced location (i.e.: `.tmp`)

Answer (score -1):

The solution was pretty easy. Turns out that I didn't had the Grunt dependencies added for production env, only for development env in my `package.json`. I've added them and worked perfectly.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "sails": "^1.0.2",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^0.13.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt": "1.0.1", // I've added these two lines
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2" // I've added these two lines
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3",
    "@sailshq/htmlhint": "^0.9.16",
    "@sailshq/lesshint": "^4.6.6",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2"
},
```

Comment: Both grunt and sails-hook-grunt are devDependencies and therefore should not be added to the dependency section. If you observe the Heroku logs, you'll see there is a devDependencies pruning step which removes these packages from your production environment.  This is important to maintain a cleaner production system. Adding a postinstall step as suggested by Phillip M. is better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll only leave my answer here because your comment could be useful to others. I point this out because I've received a downvote, even when I've already selected Phillip M.'s answer as the correct one.